# WebView vs Chromium. В чем разница?

Tags: android-sdk, android, webview

Какая разница между "обычным" WebView и WebView основанном на Chromium? Чем второй лучше/хуже?

Comment: Чего закрывают-то? Человек спрашивает конкретные различия между двумя программными решениями, нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычный WebView - старый, основаный на Chromium - новый. По сути это вся разница между ними. Новый поддерживается на новых девайсах, умеет больше стандартов, быстрее, что-то устаревшее удалено и т.п. Просто новая версия.

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html - здесь различия на уровне кода

https://www.timroes.de/2013/11/23/old-webview-vs-chromium-webview/ - здесь разница в скорости

http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/android-4-4-kitkat-browser-chrome-webview - здесь обзор ситуации